# I want to compare two column which has different date format

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I want to compare two column which has different date format.

`REQ_END_TIME` = `03-APR-18 06.15.30.000000000 AM`
`SENDDATE` = `4/3/2018`

Both have same dates , so i just want to validate date part is same or not by skipping timestamp.
`SENDDATE` format is `M/D/YYYY`

How can I change any of it to make it similar to validate with query.

Database - Oracle

Comment: Convert both to `date`. If you are storing them with format, you are using a `varchar/char`, don't do that: always use the appropriate datatype.

Comment: Don't store dates and time as varchar. Ever. And this will never be a problem you need to solve ever again. It's best that you spend your time now learning how to convert these to store them properly as dates instead of figuring out how to convert them or compare the string representation of the datetimes on the fly.

Comment: How to convert a column to date format?

Comment: I don't know how the earlier responders **know** the data type of your columns. It is not clear from your post. Is `SENDDATE` a string, or is it actually a `DATE` in the database? You can find out easily with the `DESCRIBE` command - `DESCRIBE TABLE_NAME` will show the names and the data types of each column in a table called `TABLE_NAME`. Please check the data type of the two columns and add your findings to your post.

Comment: @mathguy, indeed perhaps `REQ_END_TIME` is a `TIMESTAMP` and `SENDDATE` is a `DATE` value. Default `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` and `NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT` can be completely different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `CAST` and `to_date (with the format mask)`

```
select * from mytable
 where to_date(CAST(REQ_END_TIME as char(10)), 'DD/MM/YYYY') =
 to_date(SENDDATE, 'MM/DD/YYYY')
```

It'll return:

```
03.04.18   =   03.04.18
```

[Compiled query](https://rextester.com/NYIU18810)

Answer (score 0):

You would convert both to dates or to strings:

```
where to_date(substr(req_end_time, 9), 'DD-MON-YYYY') = to_date(send_date, 'MM/DD/YYYY')
```

Comment: `to_date('03-APR-18 06.15.30.000000000 AM', 'DD-MON-YYYY')` will not work. Better use `TO_timestamp('03-APR-18 06.15.30.000000000 AM', 'DD-MON-RR hh.mi.ssxff am')` provided they are varchar2

Answer (score 0):

Assuming SENDDATE is already in date format

```
select (to_date(REQ_END_TIME,'M/D/YYYY') - SENDDATE ) COMPARE
from mytable
```